# Correct translatation of the German word "Folgeverhalten" in the technical domain of control feedback systems

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, terminology, vocabulary, translation

I have asked various online dictionaries about the translation of the German word *Folgeverhalten*.

At these dictionaries it is translated as "subsequent behaviour" or "following behavior". I am in doubt that this is the correct translation because the example that are given there seem to target another domain.

I will use this term the field of control feedback systems (engineering). I would describe this as the "control feedback quality of a step response".

Google did not help, either. Perhaps I'm using the wrong search terms. I also read some English literature about this topics, but I could not find the English counterpart of it. Is there one at all?

Same applies to the german word *Störverhalten* (also term in control feedback)

What is here the correct translation of *Folgeverhalten* and *Störverhalten*?

---

**Edit:**

Based on the answer of mplungjan I found the translation.

- *Tracking performance — Folgeverhalten*
- *Disturbance rejection performance — Störverhalten*

It is for example used here:
http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/slcontrol/ug/tune-pid-controller-to-balance-tracking-and-disturbance-rejection-performance.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this dictionary which be helpful

http://dict.leo.org/

[Störverhalten](http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_en.html#/search=St%C3%B6rverhalten&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on) was found as *Fault response*

I found that Espacenet + google patent translate has several translations depending on context, but behaviour seems to be the word

> Somit ist ein Folgeverhalten des tatsächlichen Kraftstoffdrucks in Bezug auf den Sollkraftstoffdruck verbessert.

translated into

> Thus a *result of the behavior* of the actual fuel pressure is improved in respect to the target fuel pressure.

and

> Nachteilig an der Steuerung ist aber, dass man nur dann ein optimales Folgeverhalten erreicht...

translated into

> A disadvantage of the controller is that it only achieved an optimal *tracking behavior* when

(italics are mine)

Comment: When googling "consequential behavior" I would assume to get some results for control feedback. But I didn't. "Consequential behavior" seems not to be the correct translation. But "Fault response" is fine. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot. The single word "Tracking" seems the word I missed as keywords in google. I found that "Tracking performance" is even more used than "tracking behavior" that would also be fine. By having the term "Tracking Performance" I also found "Disturbance Rejection Performance" as translation for "Störverhalten".